# javascript html select add optgroup and option dynamically, how to?

Tags: javascript, optgroup

I have the contents of html:

```
<select name="start" id="start-sel" class="loc">
  <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
</select>
```

and javascript contents

```
$.getJSON('data/locs.json', function(locs) {
  locs.forEach(function(loc) {
    var coords = nodeCoords(loc.node);
    // Skip adding location if node isn't found in getNodes()
    if (!coords) {
      return;
    }
    var newOption = $('<option>').text(loc.name).val(loc.node);
    $('select.loc').append(newOption);
    addLocFlag(nodeCoords(loc.node));
  });
}).then(function() {
  $('select').chosen();
});

$('select#start-sel').change(function() {
  startPicked = true;
  checkStartButton();
  clearMap();
  var node = $('select#start-sel').val();
  addStartFlag(nodeCoords(node));
  zoomMapToFlags();
});
```

and contents of JSON:

```
[
  {"name": "Masuk 1", "node": "in1"},
  {"name": "Masuk 2", "node": "in2"},
  {"name": "Masuk 3", "node": "in3"},
  {"name": "Keluar 1", "node": "out1"},
  {"name": "Keluar 2", "node": "out2"},
  {"name": "Keluar 3", "node": "out3"},
  {"name": "Tiket 1", "node": "tick1"},
  {"name": "Tiket 2", "node": "tick2"},
  {"name": "Tiket 3", "node": "tick3"},
]
```

I have successfully displayed the data in the dropdown, but I want to group the data with `<optgroup>`, how to?

Comment: can you edit locs.json a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit `locs.json`, I would do

```
[
  { "label": "Optgroup 1", "nodes": [ 
    {"name": "Masuk 1", "node": "in1"},
    {"name": "Masuk 2", "node": "in2"},
    {"name": "Masuk 3", "node": "in3"},
  ]},
  { "label": "Optgroup 2", "nodes": [
    {"name": "Keluar 1", "node": "out1"},
    {"name": "Keluar 2", "node": "out2"},
    {"name": "Keluar 3", "node": "out3"},
  ]},
  { "label": "Optgroup 3", "nodes": [
    {"name": "Tiket 1", "node": "tick1"},
    {"name": "Tiket 2", "node": "tick2"},
    {"name": "Tiket 3", "node": "tick3"},
  ]}
]
```

Then you could do something like:

```
$.getJSON('data/locs.json', function(groups) {
  locs.forEach(function(group) {
    var newGroup = $('<optgroup>').attr('label', group.label);
    $('select.loc').append(newGroup);
    group.nodes.forEach(function(loc) {
      var newOption = $('<option>').text(loc.name).val(loc.node);
      newGroup.append(newOption);
    });
    addLocFlag(nodeCoords(loc.node));
  });
}).then(function() {
  $('select').chosen();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a little error, updated now. Does this work for you?